# Using bash I need to perform a find of 0 byte files but report on their existence before deletion

Tags: bash, find

**The history of this problem is:**

I have millions of files and directories on a NAS system. I found a count of 1,095,601 empty (0 byte) files. These files used to have data but were destroyed by a predecessor not using the correct toolsets to migrate data between an XSAN and this Isilon NAS.

The files were media production data, like fonts, pdfs and image files. They are no longer useful beyond the history of their existence. Before I proceed to delete them, the production user's need a record of which files used to exist, so when they browse a project folder, they can use the unaffected files but then refer to a text file in the same directory which records which files used to also be there and thus provide reason as to why certain reference files are broken.

So how do I find files across multiple directories and delete them but first output their filename to a text file which would be saved to each relevant path location?

I am thinking along the lines of:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -size 0); do
    echo "$file" >> /PATH/TO/FOUND/FILE/PARENT/DIR/deletedFiles.txt -print0 |
    xargs -0 rm ;
done
```

Comment: You really need to explain what you are required to do more carefully.  It looks as if you need to find files of size 0, and for each such file, record the name in the `deletedFiles.txt` file in the directory where the file was found as well as remove the file.  Your `echo` command echoes the name and `-print0` to a file-name (which probably doesn't exist), and then runs `xargs` with no input because the `echo` was sent to a file instead, so `xargs` just runs `rm` with no arguments which triggers a warning from `rm`.  The `-print0` probably belongs with the `find`.

Comment: Were it my problem, I'd use `find . -type f -size 0 -exec special-script.sh {} +` to generate the list of names and the `special-script.sh` would process each of its arguments in turn, handling the echo, the path for the file name and the remove (`for file in "$@"; do echo "$file" >> "$(dirname "$file")/deletedFiles.txt"; rm "$file"; done` or thereabouts).  While it probably could be done without two scripts, it is far too much like hard work for a lazybody like me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have succeeded with your input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With prompting from @JonathanLeffler I have succeeded with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
## call this script with: find . -type f -empty -exec handleEmpty.sh {} +
for file in "$@"
do
  file2="$(basename "$file")"
  echo "$file2" >> "$(dirname "$file")"/deletedFiles.txt
  rm "$file"
done
```

This means I retain a trace of the removed files in a **deletedFiles.txt** flag file in each respective directory for the users to see when files are missing. That way, they can pursue going back to archive CD's to retrieve these deleted files, which are hopefully not 0 byte files.

Thanks to @John1024 for the suggestion of using the `empty` flag rather than `size`.

Answer (score 1):

To delete each empty file while leaving behind a file called `deletedFiles.txt` which contains the names of the deleted files, try:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin find . -empty -type f -execdir bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" >>deletedFiles.txt' none {} + -delete
```

#### How it works

- `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin`

  This sets a temporary but secure path.
- `find .`

  This starts `find` looking in the current directory
- `-empty`

  This tells `find` to only look for empty files
- `-type f`

  This restricts `find` to looking for regular files.
- `-execdir bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" >>deletedFiles.txt' none {} +`

  In each directory that contains an empty file, this adds the name of each empty file to the file `deletedFiles.txt`.

  Notice the peculiar use of `none` in the command:

  ```
  bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" >>deletedFiles.txt' none {} +
  ```

  When this command is run, `bash` will execute the string `printf "%s\n" "$@" >>deletedFiles.txt` and the arguments that follow that string are assigned to the positional parameters: `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc.  When we use `$@`, it does *not* include `$0`.  It, as is usual, expands to `$1`, `$2`, ....  Thus, we add the placeholder `none` so that the placeholder is assigned is the `$0`, which we will ignore, and the complete list of file names are assigned to `"$@"`.
- `-delete`

  This deletes each empty file.

Comment: Unfortunately this only gives me one **deletedFiles.txt** file at the working directory. The users need to be able to browse nth levels deep into the tree and get to their design files and when they throw up missing file errors, they will know to look for a **deletedFiles.txt** file in that working directory which will provide a record of what was there. They can then pursue going back to archive CD's to retrieve these deleted files, which are hopefully not 0 byte files.

Comment: @chop The behavior that you describe would happen _if_ you used `-exec`  in place of `-execdir`.  Please make sure that you are using `-execdir` as shown in the command.

Comment: @chop One more thought: what version of `find` are you using?  (Run `find --version` and report the result.)

Comment: @John1024 I am testing and running these scripts and commands on both Mac OS 10.8.5 and also EMC Isilon OneFS V.7.x `GNU bash, version 4.1.11(1)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd7.1)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When `bash -c` runs,  that `none` is assigned to `$0`.  Without that `none` as a placeholder, one of the file names would be assigned to `$0` and, consequently, `"$@"` would be missing a file name.

Comment: Ah; yes, I remember being caught by that some times…It might be worth mentioning in the answer as it isn't obvious.

Comment: @chop Please run `find --version` and report the result.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good idea: I've added an explanation of that gotcha to the answer.

Comment: @John1024 - On our Isilon and Mac OS X systems, `find --version` or `find -v` does not return anything valid.

Comment: @chop Well, that is unfortunate.  I didn't find documentation online for your OSX version 10.8.5 but I found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) that the default `find` installed with Mac OSX 10.9 does support `--execdir` and claims the same functionality for it.  (Mac users, however, often seem to have non-standard utilities installed in place of the default ones supplied by Apple.)  If I had access to a Mac, I would test it there but I don't.  I see that you found a  shell-based solution that works for you and that is good.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
find . -type f -size 0 -exec rm -v + |
sed -e 's%^removed .\./%%' -e 's/.$//' >deletedFiles.txt
```

If your `find` is too old to support `-exec ... +` you'll need to revert to `-exec rm -v {} \;` or refactor to

```
find . -type f -size 0 -print0 |
xargs -r -0 rm -v |
sed -e 's%^removed .\./%%' -e 's/.$//' >deletedFiles.txt
```

The brief `sed` script is to postprocess the output from `rm -v` which looks like

```
removed ‘./bar’
removed ‘./foo’
```

(with some funny quote characters around the file name) on my system.  If you are fine with that output, of course, just omit the `sed` script from the pipeline.

If you know in advance which directories contain empty files, you can run the above snippet individually in those directories.  Assuming you saved the snippet above as a script (with a proper shebang and execute permissions) named `find-empty`, you could simply use

```
for path in /path/to/first /path/to/second/directory /path/to/etc; do
    cd "$path" && find-empty
done
```

This will only work if you have absolute paths (if not, you can run the body of the loop in a subshell by adding parentheses around it).

If you want to inspect all the directories in a tree, change the script to print to standard output instead (remove `>deletedFiles.txt` from the script) and try something like

```
find /path/to/tree -type d -exec sh -c '
    t=$(mktemp -t find-emptyXXXXXXXX)
    cd "$1" &&
      find-empty | grep . >"$t" &&
        mv "$t" deletedFiles.txt ||
        rm "$t"' _ {} \;
```

This uses a temporary file so as to avoid updating the timestamp of directories which do not contain any empty files.  The `grep .` is used purely for side effect; if any (non-empty) lines are printed, it will return success, whereas otherwise, it will report failure; this way, we know whether or not to move the temporary file to the target directory.

Comment: If it weren't for the `-print0`, you could use `tee` in the pipeline as well.

Comment: I tried your second option, which works in as far as removing the 0 byte files but I am unsure of where the report file is going? Ultimately, if there are 6 instances of 0 byte files across 3 different directories, I would want to see 3 **deletedFiles.txt** files in the relevant paths. I hope that makes sense.